# Laravel 5.1 Date_Format Validator Fails on Y-m-d Format

Tags: laravel, laravel-validation, laravel-5.1, laravel-request

I'm starting to use Request objects to validate incoming post data, and I've seen examples of how others are using [date_format](http://laravel-tricks.com/tricks/validation-and-behavior-of-date-date-format-before-and-after-rules), but I can't seem to get dates to pass even though I'm using a format that passes when you use PHP's date_parse_from_format:

```
print_r(date_parse_from_format('Y-m-d','2015-07-27'));
```

**Output**

**UPDATE**: their is a warning in date_parse_from_format, but I don't understand why as it reflects the format.

```
{
    "year": 2015,
    "month": 2,
    "day": 30,
    "hour": false,
    "minute": false,
    "second": false,
    "fraction": false,
    "warning_count": 1,
    "warnings": {
      "10": "The parsed date was invalid"
    },
    "error_count": 0,
    "errors": [],
    "is_localtime": false
}
```

**Validator**

```
public function rules()
{
    return [
        'rental_id' => 'required|exists:rentals,id',
        'start_at' => 'required|date_format:Y-m-d',
        'end_at' => 'required|date_format:Y-m-d'
    ];
}
```

Using PostMan I'm sending in a payload of:

```
rental_id = 1 as text
start_at = 2015-02-30 as text
end_at = 2015-02-30 as text
```

And it throws a NotFoundHttpException, but if I comment out start_at and end_at in the validator request it passes, and enters my controllers action with the proper payload:

```
{
    "rental_id": "1",
    "start_at": "2015-02-30",
    "end_at": "2015-02-30"
}
```

Comment: Have you dumped `$request->get('start_at')` to see what the value is there?

Comment: try `'start_at' => 'required|date_format:"Y-m-d"',`

Comment: Hi @ceejayoz, the response from PostMan shows the value of the incoming payload.

Comment: Hi @KiranLM, good idea, but it didn't work.

Comment: @ceejayoz, you're half right in a way there is something funny with the incoming request data, apparently it can't be in the past.  I changed my PostMan request to be 2015-07-30 and it works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently, the date_format validation failed as I randomly chose 2015-02-30 to test my API, but that day doesn't exist as that would be February 30... oh the shame and the wasted time.  Thanks to @ceejayoz for all the help!!!

Comment: Hmm, that's odd. The underlying code should work with a future date.

Comment: The code for `validateDateFormat` would do `date_parse_from_format('Y-m-d', '2015-07-30')` and `date_parse_from_format('Y-m-d', '2015-07-10')` both of which work without errors or warnings when I try them manually.

Comment: Hi @ceejayoz, you're right got it I randomly chose a date just to test, and I managed to randomly choose the only month that has only 28 days. Sigh!

Comment: Ah ha! February 30th is what tripped you up.